# bibleref-parse package: typeset repeated books as separate entries

Tags: indexing, parsing

The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibleref-parse}%
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\pibibleverse{John 3:16;5:12;1Co 3:12-14,18}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

typesets the index

[image]

The chapter:verse for the repeated book (John) typesets on a single line. The following index format would be more useful. Here the repeated book (John) is typeset as two entries. Notice that only the semicolon, not a comma (see the entry for 1Co in both images), should issue a new index line. The style already issues a new entry when there is a change in the book name such as 1Co in these images.

[image]

I used the code `\pibibleverse{John 3:16}; \pibibleverse{Joh 5:12;1Co 3:12-14,18}` to typeset the second image. This does not seem like a good solution when creating large indexes.

Comment: Who exactly qualifies as a 'reputable source'?!

Comment: This was one of a few choices I had when I posted this. This choice was already checked. The others did not seem to apply so I left it checked. I looked at your stats and I think you are a reputable source!

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer!

Comment: I think you should contact the author of the package. There is imho no easy way to change the parsing.

Comment: I contacted the author sometime ago. I have not received an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine, Ross Moore, suggested adding the package bibleref-xidx after the document class command in the above code. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{bibleref-xidx}% Added package
\usepackage{bibleref-parse}%
\usepackage{makeidx}%
\makeindex%
\begin{document}%
\pibibleverse{John 3:16;Joh 5:12;1Co 3:12-14,18}%
\printindex%
\end{document}%
```

This seems to work except the format of the index is less desirable. Compare the following image with the above and notice difference in the location of the chapter numbers.

[image]